# reading&input data to 2d char array, and printf. in c

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have a file having data as like

```
             wavenumber wavelength  PS
        0.000000e+00    inf 1.339797e+10
        2.667793e-04    2.355200e+04    2.264711e+07
        5.335585e-04    1.177600e+04    5.774260e+06
        8.003378e-04    7.850667e+03    4.347408e+06
        1.067117e-03    5.888000e+03    2.071735e+06
        1.333896e-03    4.710400e+03    1.338209e+06
        1.600676e-03    3.925333e+03    1.010330e+06
        1.867455e-03    3.364572e+03    7.951162e+05
        2.134234e-03    2.944000e+03    6.293471e+05
        2.401013e-03    2.616889e+03    5.702861e+05
        2.667793e-03    2.355200e+03    4.124521e+05 
        //this row goes to 513 and stop
```

---

So, I made 2d array of char for that I wanted to save the character's data in the file.
But, the problem is when I call the array, it doesn't show the data I inputted.

What is the problem I made?

And, what if I wanted to save column's data as departed into each column's array like wavenumber[513], wavelength[513], powerspec[513], what should I do ?

I would be glad for your any comments on this.

```
        char data[513][3];

        //char wavenumber[513], wavelength[513], powerspec[513];
        int COL, ROW, MAX_wavenumber, MAX_wavelength, MAX_powerspec;
        int HEIGHT,WIDTH;
        HEIGHT = 513;
        WIDTH = 3;


        //input data to new array
        for(COL = 0; COL < HEIGHT; COL++){
          for (ROW = 2 ; ROW < WIDTH; ROW++){
            fscanf(fp, "%s", &data[COL-1][ROW-1]);
              printf("%s ---\n",&data[COL-1][ROW-1]); //it shows perfectly.
          }
        }

        /********* PROBLEM PART ***********/
        printf( "%s\n!!", &data[512][2]);
```

Comment: `printf( "%s\n!!", &data[512][2]);` => `printf( "%s\n!!", data[512][2]);`, drop the `&`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Why? Either is wrong. It doesn't make sense to print the null terminator.

Comment: note my non-answering: there are so many things to fix here... there's no good answer: OP should post to "coderewrite.stackexchange.com". Oh wait, that doesn't exist :)

Comment: Racist quips & terrorism apology are hardly relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot wrong here:

```
    char data[513][3];
```

That means you made room for 513 occurences of 3 characters each. What you seem to actually want is 513x3 strings. C does not have a native string type. Strings in C are just 0 terminated arrays of characters.

If you want 513 sets of 3 strings each, you can do that using a struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char wavenumber [50];
    char wavelenght [50];
    char ps [50];
} wave_data;
```

Then, to declare 513 of these, do:

```
wave_data data [513];
```

Then, to access these, you can do

```
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &data[COL-1].wavenumber);
```

Note that there are other issues in your code, such as your misuse of scanf, but this adresses your main question.

Answer (score 0):

You are going out of range in your array indexes. You can fix it by doing it as below.

```
for(COL = 0; COL < HEIGHT; COL++){
  for (ROW = 0 ; ROW < WIDTH; ROW++){
    fscanf(fp, "%s", &data[COL][ROW]);
    printf("%s ---\n",&data[COL][ROW]); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you read a string like `0.000000e+00` and store it in a string which has room for 2 characters + 1 null terminator.

`char data[513][3];` Means, "give me 513 arrays, each with size 3". Meaning that you have 513 x 3 characters. You do not have 513 x 3 strings - a string in C is a character array.

You probably want something like this instead:

```
typedef struct
{
  char str1 [LARGE_ENOUGH];
  char str2 [LARGE_ENOUGH];
  char str3 [LARGE_ENOUGH];
} data_t;

data_t data [513];
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That might be the case, but I think the origin of the bugs is a misunderstanding about how strings work in C.